# Expanse, S2E10: what song is Alex playing on the ship?

Tags: the-expanse

In S2E10 ("Cascade"), Alex is hanging out on the Rocinante and playing country music. I'm pretty certain this is a reference to Apollo 13 (both the movie and the actual mission), where the astronauts played country music on a cassette player during a television broadcast. In the movie, the song is "Honky Tonkin'" by Hank Williams, but I was unable to find out which one Alex is playing. It sounds quite similar IMHO, but the lyrics seem to be different?

Comment: "Banal trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the movie is off topic." This is a matter of interpretation IMHO. I personally _do_ appreciate the fact that the show's writers manage to subtly reference a seminal space movie from 25 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I'm so Lonesome I Could Cry* by Hank Williams.
It has also been covered numerous times by everybody from Johnny Cash to Elvis Presley to Volbeat

Alex singing:

Hank Williams:

Comment: Excellent, thanks! So it's even the same artist; now I'm pretty certain that it's indeed an intentional reference.